# Replace Space with Dash and Remove Semicolon

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex replaces empty spaces with a dash `replace(/\s+/g, "-")`.

If I also want to remove any semicolons, how do I go about adding that to the above regex?

Basically, I want this string `hello; how are you` to be `hello-how-are-you`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add `;` in `[]` - which means [groups and ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)

```
/[\s;]+/g
```

```js
const str = "hello; how are you"

const res = str.replace(/[\s;]+/g, "-")

console.log(res)
```